# Not able to run Wordcount JAR file

Tags: java, hadoop

```
hduser@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ hadoop jar wc.jar /usr/local/hadoop/input/sample.txt /usr/local/hadoop/output
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/input/sample/txt
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

Trying to run wordcount program using java 1.7 and hadoop 1.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have told hadoop your main class is "/usr/local/hadoop/input/sample.txt"

```
 jar

Runs a jar file. Users can bundle their Map Reduce code in a jar file and execute it using this command.

Usage: hadoop jar <jar> [mainClass] args...
```

you need to use this in your java code to set jar class name

```
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
```

Comment: I am working from the same example. I definitely have that `setJarByClass` call in my code but I get the same error. Even if I specify `WordCount` in the command line, it says it can't find that class. What the heck??

Comment: Ah... I totally missed those crucial 2 seconds in the video titled "WordCount: Output Path" where he selects the `WordCount` class for the *Main class* input field in the last dialog box you are shown when exporting the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

You have not followed the correct syntax.

hadoop jar *jar_location main_class input_path output_path*

Assuming that the main class name is "WordCount" and the wc.jar is located in your PWD:

**hadoop jar wc.jar Wordcount /usr/local/hadoop/input/sample.txt /usr/local/hadoop/output**

Answer (score 0):

job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);

as mentioned by Hector doesn't solve the issue. It is just a vague guess. I still get the original symptom. Please test answers before posting !

See this comment: [Hadoop query regarding setJarByClass method of Job class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912267/hadoop-query-regarding-setjarbyclass-method-of-job-class)

I will paste the referred link here just in case it goes away someday:

---

Hi, this call,

job.setJarByClass

tells Hadoop which jar to use. But we also tell Hadoop which jar to use on
the command line,

hadoop jar your-jar parameters

Why do we need this in both places?

Thank you,

### Mark

Answer:
The jar in the command line might only be the jar to submit the map-reduce
job, rather than the jar contains the Mapper and Reducer which will be
transferred to different node.

What the hadoop jar your-jar really did, is setting the classpath and other
related environment, and run the main method in your-jar. You might have a
different map-reduce-jar in the classpath which contains the real mapper and
reducer used to do the job.

Best wishes,
Stanley Xu